# How to get bibtex working

Tags: bibtex, miktex

I am new with LaTeX and MiKTeX, so the answer may be very simple.
Tried several things, copy pasted some examples, but can't get it.

.Tex file

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[ibidem]{jurabib}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{comment}


\begin{document}

%First some renames
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Hoofdstuk}
\renewcommand\bibname{Referenties}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhoudsopgave}

\excludecomment{comment} %change exclude to include for showing in pdf too


% Article top matter
\title{Profielwerkstuk} 
\author{Remco\\
        Hi}
\date{\today}  %\today is replaced with the current date
\maketitle

\tableofcontents


\chapter{Test}
\section{Introduction}
Some text

\begin{comment}
Text
\end{comment}


%Text 

\section {Mathematical Equations}

\chapter{}
\section{Introduction}
This small document is designed to illustrate how easy it is to create a
well structured document within \cite{north}


%Create the environment for the bibliography.  Since there is only one
%reference, set the label width to be one character (I shall follow
%convention as use the number '9'.  This is because it helps to remind
%that it is the maximum number of refs that is now permitted by that
%width).

\end{document}  %End of document.
```

BibTex file(saved in the same map with same name as .tex)

```
@string{jpe = "Journal of Political Economy"}
@BOOK{north, % ‘north’ is de door jou gekozen ‘key’
author = {Douglass C. North},
year = 1990,
title = {Institutions, Institutional Change and Economic Performance},
publisher = {Cambridge: Cambridge University Press}
}
@ARTICLE{becker,
author = {Gary S. Becker},
month = feb,
year = 1962,
title = {Irrational Behavior and Economic Theory},
journal = jpe,
volume = 70,
number = 1,
pages = {1--13}
}
```

Comment: You've got no `\bibliography` and no `\bibliographystyle`. Have you looked at some basic guides to doing citations in LaTeX?

Comment: Sure, if I add \bibliography{pws}{} and \bibliographystyle{plain} I get an error: LaTeX Warning: Citation `north' on page 3 undefined on input line 48.

(D:\path\pws.bbl [3]
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@listctr 
                     
l.3 \bibitem{north}

Comment: `jurabib` is a rather specialist  package: I'd avoid loading `cite` and use one the styles it supplies (_e.g._ `jurabib`) for testing.

Comment: The first part of that message is a warning, not an error. You will get the warning until you've run `bibtex` and rerun `(pdf)latex` (twice). Also, `\bibliography` only takes one argument unless `jurabib` or `cite` redefines it. To start, comment those completely and just try with the default style so you understand the basic workflow required.

Answer (score 1):

The [`jurabib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/jurabib) package is rather specialised: it is not designed to work with general bibliography styles. Thus you need to use a style which it comes with (`\bibliographystyle{<name>}`). The package [comes with](http://texdoc.net/pkg/jurabib)

- `jurabib`
- `jureco`
- `jurunsrt`
- `jox`